# Load a Spinner in React Redux (Thunk)

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a redux store as follows:

```
const initState = {
    data:  {},

    isFetching: false,

};
```

I have a async function to fetch the data for the state:

```
const requestSideBarData = async(state, actions) => {
    const request = actions.request
    let newState = state;
    const promises = [];
    Object.keys(newState.data).forEach(element => {
        promises.push(axios.post(`${ApiEndPoints.getDropDownHeaders}${element}`,request))
    });
    const results = await Promise.all(promises);
    var index = 0;
    Object.keys(newState.data).forEach(element => {
        newState.data[element] = results[index++].data;
    })
    return newState;

};
```

And here are my begin and end reducers:

```
const fetchSideBarDataBegin = (state) => {
    return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: true,
    }
};

const fetchSideBarDataEnd = (state) => {

    return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: false,
    }
};
```

here's my actions function:

```
export const fetchSidebBatData = (dateData,selections) => {
    return {
        type: actions.FETCH_SIDEBAR_DATA_BEGIN, //Here there should be some combine action
        dateData: dateData,
        selections: selections,
        requests: {...dateData,...selections}
    }

};
```

And finally here's my reducer:

```
const reducer = ( state = initState, action ) => {
    switch ( action.type ) {

        case actionTypes.FETCH_SIDEBAR_DATA_REQUEST: return fetchSideBarData(state, action);
        case actionTypes.FETCH_SIDEBAR_DATA_BEGIN: return fetchSideBarDataBegin(state);
        case actionTypes.FETCH_SIDEBAR_DATA_END: return fetchSideBarDataEnd(state);
        default: return state;
    }
};
```

What I intend to do is to combine these three reducers into 1: so basically:

1. FETCH_SIDEBAR_DATA_BEGIN
2. FETCH_SIDEBAR_DATA_REQUEST
   and finally
3. FETCH_SIDEBAR_DATA_END

what is the right way to perform this operation?

Comment: You would have one action type FETCH_SIDEBAR_DATA and some other property in the action object which tells you whether it’s begin, request, or end.  [Here’s an answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/251039) I wrote about using abstraction to combine redux actions.

Comment: Upon reading this question again, you have got your setup very, very wrong.  You are trying to trigger API calls from within your reducer.  Don't do that.  **A reducer should not have any side effects.**  It looks like you asked a similar question and got a solid answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64603091/10431574)

Comment: Hi @LindaPaiste thank you so much and yes I got that thing after some research I have sorted it out now! Thank you so much for your help and assist :-)